# how to add a column in a df with a specific criterion

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a df and i'm trying to add a column to it based on a certain criterion. Here is the df

```
  Nos trt species days    date  int1  int2  int3 int4 intleng_total batch
1    1 sun      b3   30 2/25/13  2.73  3.50 24.35   NA         30.58     1
2    2 sun      b3   30 2/25/13  2.96  8.78 17.61   NA         29.35     1
3    3 sun      b3   30 2/25/13  3.77  3.28 25.28   NA         32.33     1
4    4 sun      b3   30 2/25/13  3.18  3.61 33.61   NA         40.40     1
5    5 sun      b3   30 2/25/13  5.34  2.57 20.24   NA         28.15     1
6    6 sun    ein9   30 2/25/13 13.64 34.73    NA   NA         48.37     1
7    7 sun    ein9   30 2/25/13 27.94 30.57    NA   NA         58.51     1
8    8 sun    ein9   30 2/25/13  9.03 11.23 39.12   NA         59.38     1
9    9 sun    ein9   30 2/25/13 16.88 30.73    NA   NA         47.61     1
10  10 sun    ein9   30 2/25/13 15.79 45.87    NA   NA         61.66     1
```

And here is the criterion that i have been trying without success

```
apply(int_comb$species,2,function (x) {if x == "b3", int_comb$mutation = "wt"})
```

Basically for all those values in `df$species == "b3"`, i want to create a column called `Mutation` and add `wt` to it and for `ein9` which i want to add `phyB` and so on..

Can i get some help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 df$Mutation <- c("phyB", "wt")[(df$species=="b3")+1] #assuming `species` column is `character` class. 
#If not convert use `(as.character(df$species=="b3")+1`
 df$Mutation
 #[1] "wt"   "wt"   "wt"   "wt"   "wt"   "phyB" "phyB" "phyB" "phyB" "phyB"
```

Or

```
setNames(c("wt","phyB"), c("b3", "ein9"))[df$species]
#   b3     b3     b3     b3     b3   ein9   ein9   ein9   ein9   ein9 
# "wt"   "wt"   "wt"   "wt"   "wt" "phyB" "phyB" "phyB" "phyB" "phyB"
```

Comment: @upendra. No problem. For multiple replacements, second one would be better.